# Kill a process ID later in a program?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, kill, pid

I'm assigning a process id, specifically a terminal that was opened that runs a script inside itself. I've got that part down. I can assign it and then kill it immediately after, but if I try and do some logic like an if logic statement and then after that logic is completed, try and kill the same processid variable, it says the process id could not be found. Ex:

```
gnome-terminal (run a command in the terminal blah blah) & p1=$!;

kill $p1
```

Works fine when done above. But if I want to do this:

```
gnome-terminal (run a command in the terminal blah blah) & p1=$!;

insert if statement with new terminal opened and closed on same line

exit if statement

kill $p1
```

I get:

> line 58: kill: {14638}: arguments must be process or job IDs

Am I perhaps doing something in the incorrect order?

Let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: Are you sure your process is still running? Seems like it exited in the meantime.

Comment: Variables are only visible within the scope of the shell.  If you are doing something else in another shell (each terminal you open runs its own shell), that shell knows nothing about your `p1` variable so it would evaluate to an empty string.

Comment: @e0k that makes complete sense actually. Thanks for the insight. Do you know of a way to make it possible to perform what I want it to do? cause the order of ops has to happen as described above :(

Comment: You can save the PID to a file somewhere.  A file, of course, would be visible to everything that has permissions on the file system.  For example, `echo $! > my_pid` when you know the PID then you can kill it with `kill $(cat my_pid)`.  Although I'd actually check to see if it's still running before I kill it.  Killing things should always be done with extreme caution.  (Good life advice too.)

Comment: The error message you got would not contain curly braces around the PID unless your inserted code modified `p1` accordingly - you'd better show real code that produces what you wrote.